# UIView and StackView removing elements, Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, uiview, storyboard

I created a custom View in a separate file from my viewController, then I add it programmatically.
To give you some context it's just a card with half screen height. Inside this card I have a vertical stackView containing:

- Horizontal stackView
- Two buttons

In this card I perform some action based on a given value from my model.
This is my code:

```
func myFunction() {

    let value: Bool! = // true or false
    
    if value {
        self.stackView.isHidden = true
    } else {
        self.button1.isHidden = true
        self.button2.isHidden = true
    }

}
```

I call my function in **viewDidAppear** lyfecycle like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.myFunction()
}
```

The problem is that when I open my view with this view I see some lag on removing elements. For example if value is true so I remove my horizontal stack view i still see it for like 0.5 seconds and then it disappear and I have my buttons only.

I thought it was the simulator and the device would perform this better, but still the same ...
Am I missing something? Is there some animation or some trick to perform this instantly?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of viewDidAppear, use viewWillAppear.

Comment: I dont know why but if I call my function in viewWillAppear it doesnt perform what's inside of it

Comment: But the function viewWIllAppear is called and even your function, just the ishidden statements don't seem to do anything?

Comment: I just tried a "work-around" by settings all my elements hidden in ViewWillAppear, and then when I need them to show I set to true and call my function in ViewDidAppear

It looks a bit better

Comment: To be honest, you should be able to set your UI in viewDidLoad if all you do is some condition checking based on a model which is set before pushing the view

Comment: So you suggest to hide everything in viewWillAppear and to call my function in viewDidLoad?

Comment: No, just set your properties in viewDidLoad (call myFunction in viewDidLoad) based on your model and thats all, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear is not necessary at all

Comment: If I call it on viewDidLoad my if statement is not performed. value it's always true so i never have the 2 button hidden